# Cannot Understand the Tail-end Insertion of Linked List in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, data-structures, linked-list

I'm just new in Kotlin and just started learning the Data Structures. I'm trying to implement the linked list with the help of the book but how they did the tail end insertion by creating the append function is crossing over my mind. here's the code of the function...

```
private var head: Node <T>? = null
private var tail: Node<T>? = null

private fun isEmpty():Boolean{
    return size==0
}
//1
fun append(nodeValue: T){
if (isEmpty()){
        push(nodeValue)
        return
    }
```

I can understand this part of the code that if the list is empty then there will be the same implementation as what I did with head insertion by creating a push function. The confusion starts now...

```
//2
tail?.nextNode = Node(nodeValue)
//3
tail = tail?.nextNode
```

literally, I can't understand what's happening is //2 and //3 plus there're not many resources of Kotlin Data Structures through which I can find a way out.
Please spare me if there is any wrong with asking the question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just linking the current tail to a newly created node, and then setting that same newly created node as the new current tail.

Comment: Are you not understanding the syntax or the logic?

Comment: I'm not understanding the logic behind. Please elaborate.

Comment: I can't understand the logic behind. Please elaborate sir!

Comment: @AdilNehal isn't Michael's comment sufficient? What else do you not understand?

Comment: Ah Thanks! I understood the first comment! Thank yiu so much sir!  & Thanks all other, Thanks for your time gentlemen/women.